# Divide bootstrap 4 card footer into 2 sections

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am trying to work with the bootstrap 4 card footer system and need to have 2 buttons side by side in the footer, but I want to have them fill the available space.

For example:
[see here for current bootstrap footer button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sfFv.jpg)

This buttons uses all available space for its background. I want to modify it to have the green check in part on the left, and then a red button on the right. Again I want them to fill the available space in The footer like in the picture, but they are in the same footer, and are the same width in the footer. I do not simply want floating buttons in the footer.

This is my code to produce a single full footer button:

```
<a class="card-footer" style="background-color:#85e085">
    Check In
</a>
```

This is the code I have to make a 2 button footer that doesn’t produce the expected output:

```
<div class="row">
    <a class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#85e085">
        Check In
    </a>
    <a class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#85e777">
        Check In
    </a>
</div>
```

I’ve tried making a div for the footer and adding the buttons in rows with column classes, I’ve tried messing with flex boxes, nothing seems to give me the expected result. Any guidance would be appreciated!

EDIT:
This is my final code that I used after taking the accepted answer into account:

```
<div class="container card-footer" style="padding:0!important;">
    <div class="row" style="margin:0!important;" >
        <a class="col-6" style="background-color:#85e085;text-align:center;padding:1em 0em">
            Check In
        </a>
        <a class="col-6" style="background-color:#85e777;text-align:center;padding:1em 0em;">
            Check In
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have to force `padding` / `margin` to zero on the `card-footer` and `row`, like I did... Then the links should display like you wish.

I don't get why you escape the double-quotes in the HTML.

```html
<!-- CSS only -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      A card
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
      <h4 class="card-title">Card title</h4>
      <p class="card-text">Some text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer" style="padding:0!important;">
      <div class="row" style="margin:0!important;">
        <a class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#85e085;text-align:center;">
                Check In
              </a>
        <a class="col-sm-6" style="background-color:#85e777;text-align:center;">
                Check In
              </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: I’m using php to serve HTML and I forgot to remove the escapes.